# redirect not work properly in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Halo, i'm using ajax to post form into controller codeigniter. I want to redirect after ajax post, but controller doesn't redirect.

This is my ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:form.attr("action"),
        data:form.serialize(),

        success: function(){

         },
        error: function(){
        alert("failure");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

this is my controller

```
public function checkout_data(){
    $this->account_model->checkout_simpan();
    redirect('produk/payment/last_steps');
}
```

this is my form

```
<form class="form-horizontal col-md-offset-3" id="form-checkout" action="<?php echo base_url('produk/payment/checkout_data');?>">
```

What wrong with my code ?

Comment: You need to redirect at ajax success function using javascript not from PHP

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it **wrong**.

What are you doing now:
when you send ajax-request to your server, method `checkout_data` is executed, and in it there's a redirect to another url. But it works on **server**. So, after redirecting to `produk/payment/last_steps`, method `last_steps` (or whatever is binded to this url) is executed and it's contents returned back to ajax-request.

What you need to do:

use javascript functions to redirect. Usually it's a `document.location`
E.g. `document.location = "some/new/url"`.
So I suppose your `checkout_data` method should return some string. that contains url for redirect. For example:

```
public function checkout_data(){
    $this->account_model->checkout_simpan();
    echo 'produk/payment/last_steps';
}
```

And in success of `ajax` you can use:

```
success: function( data ) {
    // console.log( data ) // uncomment to check what is received
    document.location = data; 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Check your path properly
2 )(important) Check Your Controller there is unwanted space in it remove all these